# Versão popular para a expressão "Se Faz Favor" de Portugal

Tags: português-europeu, girias

Houve um livro publicado no fim dos anos 90 (creio) no Brasil titulado "Se faz favor". E o subtitulo era algo como "expressões de rua típicas portuguesas".  Mas minha memória jura que o título era uma versão de rua dessa frase, como "chifaz favor".

Mais de uma vez tentei achar uma referência a esse livro, acho que até olhei os arquivos da Folha de São Paulo, onde creio haver lido o artigo sobre o livro. Olhando de novo agora em sites de livros antigos nada resulta para "se faz favor". Fiz umas variaçoes de palavras chave no [site ISBN Brasil](http://www.isbn.bn.br/website/consulta/cadastro) mas também nada.

Pode ser que o livro seja obscuro mesmo e que não há variações para SFF, mas se houver algo corriqueiro acredito que posso reconhecer.

Comment: [Será que a sua memória não te pregou uma peça?](http://www.estantevirtual.com.br/silgambarra/Guilherme-Augusto-Simoes-Dicionario-de-Expressoes-Populares-Portuguesas-sinopse-na-Descricao-137263666)

Comment: Que eu conheça e bem falado é "se faz favor" ou "por favor". Claro que há quem diga "fachavor" erradamente, não sei se será esse o caso?

Comment: @JorgeB. Realmente, se tivesse sido eu a perguntar, não teria outro remédio senão aceitar essa resposta.

Comment: @Jorge, you already disclosed you're a classic guy :) Legal "fachavor", mas o site do ISBN tá fora do ar de novo... Espero que o "porfa" em espanhol um dia entre no dicionário :P ..... O fachavor só me mostra 39 resultados no Google, e o que mais aparece é esta pérola do rap português: [Gato Fedorento - Rap dos Matarruanos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=67&v=mrZf_9kQN6U)

Comment: @E_net4, tem outro remédio: esperar mais. Se o Jorge quiser pesquisar e compilar uma resposta, certamente terá meu agradecimento, mas não necessariamente um aceite como correta.

Comment: O fachavor é usado no dia a dia, não é escrito

Comment: Então é impossível fazer um análise do seu uso se não for um documentário em vídeo? @Jorge

Comment: @bfavaretto, seu comentário tinha me escapado..! Não é esse, era mais pop e pequeno, mas que calhau interessante: 1 quilo de livro, 700 páginas! Olhei de primeira e ups, 59 pratas... mas são só 16 euricos, feito. Se por acaso vc tinha intenção de comprar esse, me dá um toque. Deixo também o ISBN, ainda tem outros exemplares pela web: 9789722017312

Comment: Valeu @brasofilo. Depois você conta se o livro é bom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Schifaizfavoire - Dicionário de Português (1994), foi escrito pelo mineiro Mário Prata que andou morando uns tempos em Portugal e foi recolhendo diferenças locais para o português do Brasil. O mesmo autor escreveu 'Estúpido Cupido', novela de 1976 que se passava nos anos 60 de enorme sucesso na TV Globo sendo também a última produção da emissora em preto e branco no horário das 19 horas.

Comment: Estou curioso para ler o livro.

Comment: O livro é um clássico (do humor)!! Tirou essa do baú, hein? (quero dizer, o livro é antigo). +1

Comment: Muito bom o livro, acabei de ler. Recomendo a todos (os brasileiros, pelo menos).

Answer (score 5):

The title of the book you mentioned is ["Schifaizfavoire - Dicionário de Português"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schifaizfavoire_-_Dicion%C3%A1rio_de_Portugu%C3%AAs), by Mario Prata, which was a humorous attempt at spelling SFF the way the Portuguese pronounce it.  In current Brazilian Portuguese, people say...

- Por favor
- Faça-me o favor
- Por obséquio

Comment: In current European Portuguese, people say "faxabor".

Comment: @ANeves  Entendo que um minhoto troque o "v" pelo "b".  Mas os habitantes do sul diriam "faxa**b**or"?

Comment: Não, Centaurus, acho que não... tens razão nisso!